# pandas merge dataframes on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

lets say I have a parent df:

parent_df:

```
id

11.0_A
121.0_B
433.0_A
32.0_A
12.0_B
```

and I have two other dataframes df_A and df_B.

df_A:

```
id, name
.
.
11, abc
433, xyz
32, jkl
```

df_B:

```
id, name
.
.
121, mno
12, pqr
```

I wish to merge `parent_df` with the appropriate df_A or df_B depending on the rows.

expected result:

parent_df

```
id,        name

11.0_A,     abc
121.0_B,    mno
433.0_A,    xyz
32.0_A,     jkl
12.0_B,     pqr
```

How do i achieve this?

I know to merge two df i could simply do:

```
parent_df = parent_df.merge(df_A, on=['id'], how='inner')
```

but this is not the case, I need to handle a condition perhaps split the `id` after `.0_` as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` and `explode`, followed by a merge with the concatenation of `df_A` and `df_B`:

```py
df_res = parent_df.merge(
    pd.concat((
        pd.concat((df_A, pd.DataFrame(['A' for _ in range(len(df_A))], columns=['AB'])), axis=1),  # add a column with 'A'
        pd.concat((df_B, pd.DataFrame(['B' for _ in range(len(df_B))], columns=['AB'])), axis=1),  # add a column with 'B'
    )),  # concatenate df_A and df_B, enriched by 'AB' column
    how='left',
    left_on=['AB', 'id_AB'],
    right_on=['AB', 'id'],
    suffixes=('_x', '_y'),
)[['id_x', 'name']].rename(columns={'id_x': 'id'})
```

Assuming that `parent_df`, `df_A` and `df_B` are the followings:

```py
import pandas as pd

parent_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['11.0_A'],
        ['121.0_B'],
        ['433.0_A'],
        ['32.0_A'],
        ['12.0_B'],
    ], columns=['id']
)

df_A = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [11, 'abc'],
        [433, 'xyz'],
        [32, 'jkl'],
    ],
    columns=['id', 'name']
)

df_B = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [121, 'mno'],
        [12, 'pqr'],
    ],
    columns=['id', 'name']
)
```

`df_res` is:

```sh
        id name
0   11.0_A  abc
1  121.0_B  mno
2  433.0_A  xyz
3   32.0_A  jkl
4   12.0_B  pqr
```

Comment: `KeyError: "['id_y'] not found in axis"`